# concat two strings totalling >4000 characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to combine two columns from one table (A) into on column in a second table (B). The column in table B is set as CLOB to hold the large amount of data, however when I run the script I get a message that the result of my string concatenation is too long.

```
INSERT INTO berkshire.tim_rebuttal_prod(
,INVEST_OR_UWG
)
SELECT 
,(INVEST_OR_UWG || INVEST_OR_UWG2)
FROM berkshire.stage_rebuttal
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't see any reason why CLOB shouldn't hold that, but I'm not an Oracle guy, hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'm thinking maybe its not the CLOB but the || concat function itself?

Comment: Well || is designed to handle CLOB, are both fields CLOB?  What happens if you try SELECT INVEST_OR_UWG || INVEST_OR_UWG2 INTO #Test?

Comment: Convert your source fields to CLOB before concatenation using the `to_clob` function. Like: `to_clob(INVEST_OR_UWG) || to_clob(INVEST_OR_UWG2)`.

Answer (score 0):

select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,id,',').extract('//text()') order by id).GetClobVal(),',')
  from (select level as id from dual connect by level < 1050)